# Clarification on Receive Notifications from Azure Cache

Tags: azure, notifications, azure-caching

I'm working on enabling a notification when items are added/replaced on Azure Role based dedicated cache. I've followed the instruction from MSDN link provided below;

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh914156.aspx

```
//specify all possible item and region operations
DataCacheOperations allCacheOperations = DataCacheOperations.AddItem |
    DataCacheOperations.ReplaceItem;


DataCacheNotificationDescriptor ndCacheLvlAllOps
    = myTestCache.AddItemLevelCallback(allCacheOperations, myCacheLvlDelegate);



public void myCacheLvlDelegate(string myCacheName,
    string myRegion, 
    string myKey, 
    DataCacheItemVersion itemVersion,
    DataCacheOperations OperationId, 
    DataCacheNotificationDescriptor nd)
{
    //display some of the delegate parameters
    Console.WriteLine("A cache-level notification was triggered!");
    Console.WriteLine("    Cache: " + myCacheName);
    Console.WriteLine("    Region: " + myRegion);
    Console.WriteLine("    Key: " + myKey);
    Console.WriteLine("    Operation: " + OperationId.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("    DeligateID" + nd.DelegateID.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

The application receives the application on Add and replace item. However, what I've noticed is that when you perform add or replace **N** number of times for given action, the CallBack functions gets executed N number of times.

e.g.
**First** Add, notification gets triggered **1** time for AddItem operation.

**Second** Add(same key), notification gets triggered **2** times for ReplaceItem Operation (with delegateID 1 and 2)

**Third** Add(same key), notification gets triggered **3** times for ReplaceItem Operation (with DelegateID 1,2 and 3).

Could someone please help me understand why notifications are getting fired N number of times instead on **once each time** item gets added/replaced?

Thanks.